# É possível ter o mês 13 em uma data em Java?

Tags: java, datetime, formatação, data

Estava olhando a documentação da classe `Formatter` do Java 7, [nesse link da própria Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html), quando me reparei com o seguinte exemplo abaixo:

[image: Screenshot da tela do browser]

O que me intrigou foi o exemplo dado para a opção de formatação de mês, `m`: que são os números de 1 a 13.

Todos os exemplos dados para as outras opções de formatação são válidos e têm valores coerentes, o que me leva a crer que sim, é possível ter um mês 13 em Java. A questão é, que data UTC, e em qual calendário, me retornaria um mês 13?

Ou realmente esse é o único exemplo da página que não bate com a realidade, e o valor 13 foi digitado por acaso, sem pensar?

Comment: Ele é usado em sistemas de RH para que eles possam pagar o 13º salário de seus funcionários :)

Comment: @Math Não duvido que deva ser alguma gambiarra! Vamos ver se alguém sabe :D

Comment: Veja este link também, fiquei curioso com essa coisa lunática [Calendário de 13 luas](http://www.pan-portugal.com/intro/perguntas-frequentes)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Olhando mais abaixo, na documentação que você linkou tem o mesmo trecho repetido, só que dessa vez com uma explicação mais detalhada, e ela diz:

> Month, formatted as two digits with leading zeros as necessary, i.e. 01 - 13, where "01" is the first month of the year and ("13" is a special value required to support lunar calendars).

Em tradução livre:

> Mês, formatado com dois dígitos com o zero antecedendo quando necessário. Ex: 01 a 13, onde "01" é o primeiro mês do ano e ("13" é um valor especial exigido para suportar calendários lunares).

O nome do mês em inglês é [UNDECIMBER](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#UNDECIMBER) :

> Value of the MONTH field indicating the thirteenth month of the year. Although GregorianCalendar does not use this value, lunar calendars do.

Em tradução livre:

> Valor do campo MONTH indicando o décimo terceiro mês do ano. Apesar do GregorianCalendar não usar esse valor, calendários lunares usam.

(In)felizmente, não existe uma classe padrão do Java que suporte o calendário lunar, mas é possível encontrar implementações <strike>feitas por lunáticos</strike> como essa aqui: [hoveychen/lunar_calendar @ GitHub](https://github.com/hoveychen/lunar_calendar/blob/master/LunarCalendar/src/com/eternizedlab/lunarcalendar/LunarCalendar.java)

Ao tentar usar o mês 13 em um objeto do calendário gregoriano, obtemos o primeiro mês do ano seguinte. Exemplo:

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Lunatico {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        c1.set(2015, Calendar.DECEMBER, 20);   //data: 20/12/2015

        Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        c2.set(2015, Calendar.UNDECIMBER, 20); //data: 20/13/2015

        System.out.println(String.format("Dia normal: %1$te/%1$tm/%1$tY", c1));
        System.out.println(String.format("Dia (quase) lunático: %1$te/%1$tm/%1$tY", c2));

        System.out.println(String.format("\nMês: %1$tB", c2)); //escrevendo por extenso
    }
}
```

Resultado:

> Dia normal: 20/12/2015
>   Dia (quase) lunático: 20/01/2016
>
> Mês: Janeiro

Repare que dentro do `String.format()` eu usei o `m`, conforme explica a documentação.

Comment: Valeu, Math! Matou! Essa página é tão grande que nunca percebi que ela meio que repete duas vezes as explicações! Passou batido! :)

Comment: Sim, ela é gigante mesmo, achei meio que na sorte. E é um fato curioso a se saber :)

Comment: Meus amigos do Facebook ficaram intrigados, e vou fazer o teste... Como seria o "nome" desse mês?! :)

Comment: @carlosrafaelgn depois que descobrir nos conte, também estou curioso, mas não to com a mão na massa agora para fazer o teste.

Comment: Que tal Onzembro? :P

Comment: Bem que eu achava que programadores Java eram uns lunáticos, eis a prova!

Comment: Sugiro Trezembro, mais ele já tem nome, vejam [Calendário Lunar](http://www.lawoftime.org/thirteenmoon/tutorial.html)  :P

Comment: Seguindo a lógica de outubro, novembro, dezembro seria onzembro haha

Comment: @abfurlan Assim que eu terminar o que estou fazendo, vou fazer o teste! Estou chocado! :D

Comment: Lá se foi meu final da tarde, agora vou pesquisar sobre calendários lunares, por que dezembro e não dozembro, testar o DateTime e por aí vai :-/

Comment: @carlosrafaelgn Achei o nome do danado: [UNDECIMBER](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#UNDECIMBER), precisamos ver como fica isso em Português. Vou coletar mais umas informações legais e melhorar a resposta :)

Comment: Gostei do trocadilho usando lunáticos.

Answer (score 12):

Alguns calendários podem ter 13 meses, como por exemplo o [calendário igbo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Igbo_calendar).

A principal razão para um calendário lunar ter 13 meses é que cada ciclo lunar tem 28 dias aproximadamente (4 semanas). Se multiplicarmos 28 por 13, o resultado dá 364 dias. Ou seja, em um ano temos 13 ciclos lunares completos (e mais 1 ou 2 dias sobrando). Nos calendários puramente lunares, cada ciclo lunar corresponde a um mês, e portanto o ano teria 13 meses.

Entretanto, nem todos os calendários com 13 meses são necessariamente lunares, como por exemplo o [calendário copta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coptic_calendar) e o [calendário etíope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethiopian_calendar). Nestes calendários temos 12 meses com 30 dias cada e um décimo-terceiro mês curto, com apenas 5 dias.

Alguns outros calendários, apesar de baseados nos ciclos lunares, têm 12 meses, tais como o [calendário islâmico](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_calendar) e o [calendário hindu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_calendar).

Em alguns anos, o [calendário hebraico](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_calendar) têm um décimo-terceiro mês bissexto também.

O nome do décimo-terceiro mês é [*undezembro*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecimber), que seria o décimo-primeiro mês (sem contar janeiro e fevereiro), porque dezembro era o décimo mês antes de [os romanos fazerem uma reforma no calendário no ano 46 antes de Cristo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_calendar). Igualmente, o décimo-quarto mês, para calendários aonde isso possa existir, chama-se *duodezembro*.

Comment: Fantástico, Victor! Seus conhecimentos sobre calendários assombram! :D

Comment: Recuperei meu fim de tarde, não preciso pesquisar mais nada :)